# php Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\middle.php on line 3

Tags: php

I am making a website and am getting thrown this error when I go to www.mydomain.org.
This code ***Works*** when going to http://mydomain.org/index.php?id=home

How do I fix this as I don't want people to have to type in the /index.php?id=home

```
<div id="middle_main">
    <?php   
          $page = $_GET['id']; 
          if ($page == "") { include "pages/home.html"; } 
          else { include "pages/$page.html"; } 

    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if it is set, if not, set it to 'home':

```
$page = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 'home';
```

Then you don't need an if statement to check it is set:

```
include "pages/$page.html";
```

Comment: Ah much thanks. I actually do still need the if statement. It throws a syntax error if it is removed, but it works with your added line how I want it to.

Comment: You shouldn't need an if statement anymore to check that the variable has value. You will need to check whether the value is a 'valid section' of your site though.

Answer (score 0):

**Notices** are really recent in PHP development, and they are *not* errors, which means you don't have to *fix* them. Yet, this is a very good practise to do so.

The `undefined index` notice warns you that you are trying to read an array index that hasn't been initialised. In your case, you try to read the `home` index of the `$_GET` array. When your URL is `something.php?home=something`, then `$_GET['home']` is initialised automatically, and no notice appears. However, when you access `something.php`, this index isn't set, which explains the notice !

In your code, you need to check whether this index is set, and assign it a default value when it isn't.

```
$page = isset($_GET['home']) ? $_GET['home'] : 'home';
```

In this case, if the `home` index isn't set, `$page` will be set to "home". See http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators if you want to know more about the ternary operator (? and :) which I've just used.

Comment: Since when are notices _really recent_ in PHP development?

Comment: I guess that experience speaking, I remember using PHP far before notices were implemented, and I'm not *that* old. With PHP 6 alpha now out, maybe it's been a while... Anyway, that not old :p